# Move cursor back to first column in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, move, text-cursor

I am beggining in shell script, which does some simple stuff. I have only a simple question:

After a printf, the cursor stays in a specific position of the screen. I want it to go back to the first column, on the same line, so I can use printf again on the same line. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks a lot,
R.

Answer (score 3):

Add `\r` to the end of the format string.